# How can I use flutter uploader and chunk uploader on the same request

Tags: flutter, file-upload, background-process, chunked, dio

I am searching for a way to upload a chunked image in a background task in flutter for Android. I already took a look at [flutter_uploader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader) and [chunked_uploader](https://pub.dev/packages/chunked_uploader) plugins but it don't seems they are compatible.
Here is the documentation for the API I am trying to upload to:
[piwigo upload async endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovOU3.png)

Right now I am using a non chunked request with Dio to another endpoint:

```dart
void uploadPhotos(List<Asset> photos) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  Map<String, String> queries = {"format":"json", "method": "pwg.images.upload"};

  photos.forEach((element) async {
    ByteData byteData = await element.getByteData();
    List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    FormData formData =  FormData.fromMap({
      "category": widget.category,
      "pwg_token": prefs.getString("pwg_token"),
      "file": MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        imageData,
        filename: element.name,
      ),
      "name": element.name,
    });

    Response response = await API.dio.post("ws.php",
      data: formData,
      queryParameters: queries,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.data);
      if(json.decode(response.data)["stat"] == "ok") {
        SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
          content: Text("Successfully uploaded ${element.name}"),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        );
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      }
    } else {
      print("Request failed: ${response.statusCode}");
    }
  );
}
```

So, is there a way to use the two plugins for a single request and if not, what should I use to fulfill my needs ?

Comment: do you found any solution?

Comment: Do you found any solution to upload chunked in flutter uploader?